# ASP.NET MVC - Ajax.BeginForm vs Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I've noticed when I use Ajax.BeginForm (with a submit button) that the Model is passed to the Controller but when I use an Ajax.ActionLink it is not passed - or at least I have not discovered how to tap into it.

First question:  How do you determine which is the better route to take?

Now, for a little deeper dive into one sample scenario:  I have a model that has a couple dozen simple data type properties and a few List properties.  The Create/Edit View is rendered with a Html.BeginForm().  The submit button returns the entire view model and I can then go through it and save all the data to the DB via the DB Model.  Like I said I have a few List pieces as well.  For example, I have a List of credit cards accepted which I render as a series of check boxes, a List of Services Provided also rendered as a list of check boxes.  All of these are easy to deal with on the Form Post.  However, I have one List that is basically a free-form text entry and I would like to have the textbox with an Add button followed by all of the List items, each with a delete button.

My Create/Edit view looks something like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC.ViewModels.DirectoryEdit>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="Column12">
        <div class="Shadow"></div>
        <h2 class="h2row"><%= Model.PageTitle%></h2>
        </div>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>

        <fieldset>
            <%--<legend>Fields</legend>--%>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style = "width:20em;" })%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)%>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address1, new { style = "width:20em;" })%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1)%>
            </div>
...                

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.LookupAccepts)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <hr />
                <% foreach (var a in Model.MyAccepts)
                   {
                       if (a.Checked)
                       { %>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="AcceptIDs" checked="checked" value="<%: a.ID %>" /> <%: a.Name%><br />
                    <% }
                       else
                       { %>                    
                        <input type="checkbox" name="AcceptIDs" value="<%: a.ID %>" /> <%: a.Name%><br />
                <% }
                   } %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.LookupServices)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <hr />
                <% foreach (var a in Model.MyServices)
                   {
                       if (a.Checked)
                       { %>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ServiceIDs" checked="checked" value="<%: a.ID %>" /> <%: a.Name%><br />
                    <% }
                       else
                       { %>                    
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ServiceIDs" value="<%: a.ID %>" /> <%: a.Name%><br />
                <% }
                   } %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyLicenses)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <hr />
                <% Html.RenderPartial("EditLicense", model: Model); %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")%>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

The Partial View looks like:

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%@ Import namespace="RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC" %>

<% foreach (var license in Model.MyLicenses) { %>

<% } %>

My thought train for setting it up this way is pretty straight forward (I think it is anyways).  I only have something to Ajax on the License section.  I want to add one string after another without losing all of the information for the main model.  And after the add is done I want to update the partial view with the updated List for it.

There is probably a better way to do this than what I laid out and if so, lay it on me.  The main part I am trying to figure out right now (and quickly) is whether Ajax.ActionLink (and my Extension methods for it) are the right direction to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Ajax.BeginForm simply ajaxifies the given form and when you submit it the values of all input fields that it contains are sent to the server. The only difference with a normal form is that the they are sent using AJAX.

On the other hand Ajax.ActionLink generates a simple anchor tag which performs an AJAX request to the given url. It won't send any additional values to the server unless you specify it.

> How do you determine which is the better route to take?

Personally I don't use any of those. I use standard Html.BeginForm and Html.ActionLink and write the code manually to AJAXify them unobtrusively with jQuery (if I need to use Ajax of course).

For your scenario of implementing dynamic list editing you may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

Comment: do you have an example where it is done manually instead of the helpers way? Also any reason why you don't like using the helpers?